# Remove grey border from jfreechart Piechart

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jfreechart

I am using JFreeChart in a JSP page that is send from a servlet.

However I can't remove the grey border around the chart (see screenshot).

[jfreechart with border http://www.craenhals.eu/images/jfreechart.png](http://www.craenhals.eu/images/jfreechart.png)

How can i remove that?

I use the following code to generate the chart in my servlet:

```
    PiePlot plot = new PiePlot(dataset);
    StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator labels = new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator("{0} = {2}");
    plot.setLabelGenerator(labels);
    plot.setInteriorGap(0);
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
    plot.setBaseSectionOutlinePaint(Color.blue);
    plot.setBaseSectionPaint(Color.green);
    plot.setShadowPaint(Color.black);
    plot.setShadowXOffset(0);
    plot.setShadowYOffset(0);
    plot.setOutlineVisible(false);


    chart = new JFreeChart("", plot);

    chart.setPadding(new RectangleInsets(0, 0, 0, 0));


    chart.setBorderVisible(false);
    chart.clearSubtitles();
```

What am I missing here? I also use this code in my JSP to embed the image:

```
<img
    src="<c:url value="/beheerder/statistieken?actie=chart_contactwijze"/>"
    title="Contactwijze" border="0"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grey border is the background of the chart. 
To change it, just add the following line : `chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white)`

Answer (score 8):

plot.setOutlineVisible(false);

did the trick for me.

Answer (score 6):

```
plot.setShadowPaint(null)
```

This worked for me.